# laravel роуты и контроллеры

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Ребят, подскажите, можно ли делать вот такие запросы в роутах? просто 'TovarController@tovar' и 'MenuController@menu' не работают как то вместе, только начал изучать фреймворки и не до конца понимаю взаимодействие роутов с контроллерами.

```
        Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');  // Тут вывод страниц
        Route::get('/', 'TovarController@tovar');  // Вывод товаров из бд
        Route::get('/', 'MenuController@menu');  // Боковое меню сайдбар
        Route::get('/contacts', 'SiteController@contacts');
        Route::get('/category/{id}', 'SiteController@category');


        Так правильно?
        Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');  // Тут вывод страниц
        Route::get('tovar', 'TovarController@tovar');  // Вывод товаров из бд
        Route::get('menu', 'MenuController@menu');  // Боковое меню сайдбар
        Route::get('/contacts', 'SiteController@contacts');
        Route::get('/category/{id}', 'SiteController@category');
```

Comment: Роут обрабатывается одним экшеном контроллера. Нельзя обрабатывать роут двумя, тремя и более экшенами.

Comment: А можете на примере небольшом показать как надо прописывать роуты, в моем случае?

Comment: Чем ваш случай отличается от тысячи других?

Comment: Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');  // Тут вывод страниц
        Route::get('tovar', 'TovarController@tovar');  // Вывод товаров из бд
        Route::get('menu', 'MenuController@menu');  // Боковое меню сайдбар
        Route::get('/contacts', 'SiteController@contacts');
        Route::get('/category/{id}', 'SiteController@category');  так правильно:?

Comment: Вы видимо не понимаете что такое роут. Роут это фактически УРЛ по которому доступна та или иная страница вашего приложения. `Route::get('tovar', 'TovarController@tovar');` регистрирует урл `tovar` при попадании на который будет выполняться экшен `TovarController@tovar`.

Comment: Я не понимаю как мне вывести боковое меню из бд без роута, или для этого есть другие способы

Comment: Экшен, который обрабатывает роут, делает __все__ - получает товары из БД, получает данные для меню, получает еще фиг знает что и всю эту кучу данных отдает в шаблонизатор.

Comment: То есть правильнее всего все манипуляции которую будут происходить на главной должны быть в одном экшене 'SiteController@index' ?

Comment: Никак иначе вы не сможете сделать.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял, спасибо, а как тогда теперь выводить боковое меню если там метод был menu и он выводился нормально, а сейчас метод index

Comment: Взять код из метода `menu`, перенести его в другой экшен и немного подпилить?

Comment: Хорошо, что бы понять, один роут должен обрабатывать только один экшен и при этом могут быть разные методы? Вот так правильно будет? Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@menu');

Comment: Что вы написали тут?

Comment: А вы что написали??

Comment: Я снова вам пишу - один роут (`/`) можно обработать только одним экшеном (например, `SiteController@index`). Чего вы пытаетесь добиться написав еще и `Route::get('/', 'SiteController@menu');`? Ведь это __еще один__ экшен для того же самого роута `/`.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, буду искать решение

Comment: @ilyaaa521, боковое меню вынесите лучше на layout или sidebar

Comment: Так и сделал, у меня боковое меню находится в sidebar.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/contacts', 'SiteController@contacts');
```

**/contacts** - будет в строке ввода url то есть http://localhost:8000/contacts

SiteController - тот контроллер в котором ты вызываешь функцию `@contacts` 
и в конце функции указываешь `return view`(название твоего blade, где будут отображены данные );